# error TCP DUP ACK ando others with tcp streamed when transfer a class with byte[]

Tags: wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service that in one method I use as parameter a class that have a byte[]. When I use this method, if the client is in the same computer than the service, all work fine, but if the client is in other computer, I have some problems.

If I use winshark, for example, I get the following error:

- The other error is "TCP dup ACK 61#1".
- TCP retransmission. Well, this I think that is an error because it is in red.
- TCP out of order.
- TCP fast retransmission. This is in red, so I think that is other error.

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you having though? You've given a lot of diagnostic information to help track down a problem, but you didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: How large are the byte arrays that you're trying to send?